# NSOrderedSet is not convertible to NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

I'm partly following [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/73984/make-app-like-runkeeper-part-1) tutorial from Ray Wenderlich (if you search for 'Saving the run' it should jump to the part concerning this question). I've tagged this one with 'Swift' as well, as I don't know if it is swift causing any trouble (since it's working in the tutorial which is in ObjC).

I'm currently stuck on saving the location data into the CoreData data model.

Here the code for my saveSession method:

```
func saveSession()
    {
        var newSession: Session = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Session", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!) as Session
        
        newSession.timestamp = NSDate()
        
        var tempArray = [AnyObject]()
        for newLocation in self.locationsArray {
            var location: Location = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Location", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!) as Location
            
            location.timestamp  = newLocation.timestamp
            location.latitude   = newLocation.coordinate.latitude
            location.longitude  = newLocation.coordinate.longitude
            location.altitude   = newLocation.altitude
            location.heading    = newLocation.heading
            location.horizontalAccuracy = newLocation.horizontalAccuracy
            location.verticalAccuracy = newLocation.verticalAccuracy
            
            tempArray.append(location)
        }
        
        // This is the line producing the error:
        // 'NSOrderedSet' is not convertible to 'NSManagedObject'

        newSession.locations = NSOrderedSet(array: tempArray)
    }
```

Here is my data model:

Session Entity
[image: Session Entity]

Location Entity
[image: Location Entity]

Let me know if any more code / info is needed to solve this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined the `locations` property as a "to-one" relationship. It should
be a "to-many" relationship. Then you can assign an `NSSet` or `NSOrderedSet`,
depending on whether the relationship is defined as "ordered" or not.

Comment: I did that in the session relationship, which I thought would be the one to do it in... Any ways, if I change the locations to 'to-many' and tick 'Ordered' it doesn't make the error go away